# auto fill and submit login form when actual click is required

Tags: jxbrowser

We are investigation option of replacing JavaFx WebView with JxBrowser and the following code snippet worked fine with WebView:

```
((HTMLInputElementImpl)document.getElementById("username")).setValueForUser("username");
((HTMLInputElementImpl)document.getElementById("password")).setValueForUser("password");
loginButton.click();
```

the magic was done by setValueForUser, using standard setValue("") does not work as form submit/action is disabled unless someone actually clicked to the fields.

Unfortunately I did not find correct way to implement the same logic with JxBrowser:

```
    InputElement username = (InputElement) document.findElement(By.id("username"));
    username.setValue("username");
    username.click();
    InputElement password = (InputElement) document.findElement(By.id("password"));
    password.setValue("password");
    password.click();
    loginButton.click(); // or form.submit()
```

username.click() did not help.

I'm thinking about simulating/sending mouse events to browser view, but it will be messy solution.

So it there setValueForUser alternative in JxBrowser?

Thanks,
-Alex

Comment: JxBrowser doesn't support the required form auto fill feature. I recommend that you submit a feature request using https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/tickets/new web form.

Comment: Thank you for reply, But there is not way to submit ticket without paid subscription :(  I workaround the problem with sending KeyEvents to browser component (Tab -> Tab -> click button).